# Use MsgBox in Inno Setup to ask questions before Installation

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, msgbox

How to make installer to ask a question before opening the installer?

For Example:
It will ask *"Are You Over 18?"* then user can select whether *"Yes"* or *"No"*.
If user selects *"Yes"*, installer will open. if user selects *"No"*, installer will close automatically.

I would like to use `MsgBox` feature, if I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the `MsgBox` from [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup):

```pascal
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (MsgBox('Are You Over 18?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
end;
```

---

Or as @KenWhite commented, use a custom wizard page. You can use [`CreateInputOptionPage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_createinputoptionpage) for that.